# How can I differentiate between a PyTorch Tensor and a nested tensor?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

Recently, PyTorch introduced the [nested tensor](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nested.html). However, if I create a nested tensor, e.g.,

```py
import torch

a = torch.randn(20, 128)
nt = torch.nested.nested_tensor([a, a], dtype=torch.float32)
```

and then look at its class type, it shows:

```py
type(nt)
torch.Tensor
```

i.e., the class type is just a regular PyTorch `Tensor`. So, `type(nt) == torch.Tensor` and `isinstance(nt, torch.Tensor)` will both return `True`.

So, my question is, is there a way to differentiate between a regular tensor and a nested tensor?

One way I can think of is that the `size` method to nested tensors (currently) works differently to that for regular tensors in that it requires an argument otherwise it raises a `RuntimeError`. So, a solution might be:

```
def is_nested_tensor(nt):
    if not isinstance(nt, torch.Tensor):
        return False

    try:
        # try calling size without an argument
        nt.size()
        return False
    except RuntimeError:
        return True

    return False
```

but is there something simpler that doesn't rely on something like the `size` method not changing in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an attribute for all `torch.Tensor`s called `is_nested`, but it's not documented sadly. It's only mentioned in the [FAQ](https://pytorch.org/docs/2.2/torch.compiler_faq.html#frequently-asked-questions)

```
> nt.is_nested
True
```

```
> a.is_nested
False
```